# H2 database error for SQL Server prod DB "BOOLEAN" and "CHARACTER VARYING(5)" are not comparable

Tags: sql-server, h2, bit

SQL Server has bit type column to store true and false.

In where clause we check column_name = 'false' it works fine on SQL Server (dev and prod env) but it fails in test case using H2 in memory database.

Error is:

> Values of types "BOOLEAN" and "CHARACTER VARYING(5)" are not comparable

H2 database connection related properties I use are:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:TESTDB;\
  DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;\
  MODE=MSSQLServer;\
  INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dbo\\;SET SCHEMA dbo
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

As a workaround it works fine when I use `column_name=0`, but it is hard to force everyone to use this convention in SQL.

Comment: `bit` *isn't* a boolean; it is *similar* but it does *not* fulfil the same role. You *can* compare a `bit` to the `varchar` literals `'false'` and `'true'`, however, it's not recommended. You are far better off handling the values as `0` and `1`. This should, however, be something you should be handling in your application layer; presumably you would have some kind of tickbox/true/false option, and then that would cause the application to send the correct parameter value.

Comment: H2 is not SQL Server, all RDBMS have their own uniqueness, so why would you expect something which works on SQL Server to work on H2 anyway?

Comment: @DaleK are you saying why am I using h2 and I should be using SQL server for unit test cases as well?
h2 is widely used for unit testing, it supports mode for different type of database, still I am not saying it should be 100% compatible with all databases, may be this is one scenario where h2 has limitation in SQL server mode.

Comment: The fact that T-SQL permits implicit conversions for `BIT` to string types and back for the specific values `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` is a rather obscure feature -- obscure enough that the SQL Server docs on conversion don't even cover it themselves, it's only mentioned in the docs for `BIT`. H2 can't really be blamed for not mimicking the behavior exactly, here, even though it is a shortcoming. Since `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not actually keywords, and T-SQL does not support true boolean expressions, there's little incentive to use this as opposed to treating `BIT` as the integer type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are very helpful to understand bit in SQL server, I would like to accept comment from - Jeroen Mostert as an answer.

> The fact that T-SQL permits implicit conversions for BIT to string
> types and back for the specific values 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' is a rather
> obscure feature -- obscure enough that the SQL Server docs on
> conversion don't even cover it themselves, it's only mentioned in the
> docs for BIT. H2 can't really be blamed for not mimicking the behavior
> exactly, here, even though it is a shortcoming. Since TRUE and FALSE
> are not actually keywords, and T-SQL does not support true boolean
> expressions, there's little incentive to use this as opposed to
> treating BIT as the integer type it is.